# How do I get genre metadata from video files of arbitrary formats?

Tags: delphi, metadata, firemonkey, multimedia

I want to categorise the video files that a user loads based on the genre stored in the file metadata. I know this is true for MP3 files, and the format of this data, and location at the eof is well documented,

Im looking for information on how video file metadata is formatted and where it is stored in the file(eg. how many bytes at the eof are dedicated to metadata). While I appreciate that different file formats will have different formatting methods they use to store the information, I'm trying to figure out if there is a known format for certain video file formats, or a basic model that can be applied to most file formats.

Comment: I dont have an answer, but if you try searching Riff file format, you will get results of how and what the data looks like, i assume you could then use xml or something like that to retrieve the data from the file.

Comment: @GlenMorse Who says that the file if RIFF? You can never use XML to retrieve things since XML is a markup language rather than a retrieval mechanism.

Comment: it was just a suggestion , as a way to retrieve the data from the header file as it looks like it is in  XML, format, like i said if you search RIFF (Resource Interchange File Format) you will find the format.  try this  http://www.daubnet.com/en/file-format-riff

Comment: I think you'll find the answer is a two-step process: first, identify the format; next, load metadata for that format. So, which formats does your program support?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to go threw all the video formats and get them like this..  http://www.fastgraph.com/help/avi_header_format.html

or an easier way is to use the libary all ready created, http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo